# Flex/Flash white screen in FireFox

Tags: apache-flex, firefox

We get a white screen when loading our swf in FireFox. No problem in Chrome, IE and Safari.

When we create a Flex project targeting SDK 3.2, things do work. Using 3.5, things don't work.

Anyone that had similar problems?

Comment: what do you mean with a "white screen"? The default style of flex applications has changed with SDK 3.5, so the background of the application is now white instead of gray. Is this causing your confusion?

Comment: @hering lol, no, haven't created an application with just a background ;-) The swf is loaded, but not shown. We have even created a test application with just a button, and it doesn't show. We only see white, white, white.

Comment: How do you know the swf is loaded?  Is it possible that it's an issue with with html?

Comment: Have you checked the version of Flash Player that you have installed in FireFox? Perhaps the version of Flash you require for the swf to load is higher than the version of the Flash Player plugin installed in FireFox.

Comment: - Yew swf is loaded. You can know by right clicking. Swf is loaded over the whole screen because everywhere you click you can see it's the swf.

Comment: Version is ok. We have checked that.

Comment: We have found the problem. Firefox, IIS7, flash files and GZIP don't work well together...